# Making some elements in a collapsible-set not expandable with JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile to create a tree by using nested collapsibles. As with any treeview, a parent may or may not have any children. In my current approach, collapsibles that have no children are still collapsible, alltough the collapsible part is empty as there are no children. This results in a very ugly UI. What I would like to have is a way of turning off the behaviour of expanding the collapsible, yet being able to turn it on on collapsibles that do have children.

I've already tried different solutions, like the one being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314446/need-help-to-make-non-collapsible-section-using-jquery-mobile). It uses a very simple piece of code to disable the collapsing effect:

```
 $("#page").live('pageinit', function(event) {
      $(".ui-collapsible[data-allow-collapse=false]").unbind("expand collapse");
 });
```

But that solution has the opposite effect: he is looking for a non-collapsible section while I'm looking for a non-expandable section. Just editing the answerers jsFiddle page (which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8dLw4/2/)) to reverse the effect creates very strange effects.

I've [updated that jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dLw4/19/) to show you what happens. You will notice that once you click on the last element in the collapsible-list (Section 4) it will automatically collapse all the above elements (except for the first element, as this one has the property *data-allow-collapse* set to *false*. This seems strange behaviour to me, as it collapses all elements while clicking on a different element.

Is there any way to fix that behaviour or should I take a completely different approach? All I basically want is a property like *data-allow-to-expand*, and if that is set to false nothing happens after clicking on that specific element. When set to true, it should expand as it would normally.